# dc.js pie chart drawPaths is not a function error

Tags: dc.js

```
      .width(400)
      .height(200)
      .externalLabels(20)
      .externalRadiusPadding(5)
      .drawPaths(true)
      .dimension(genderDimension)
```

This is my code but drawPaths is not working. I don't want to use 2.0 beta.

Comment: Please add more details

Comment: Yes, [drawPaths](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.pieChart.html#drawPaths__anchor) was introduced around 2.0 beta 19, but you don't have to use a beta version. You could use any of the the 2.* (for D3v3) or 3.* (for D3v4 and v5) versions, which are stable.